# session maintenance in Shoping Cart using java servlet

Tags: java, servlets

i am working on a shopping Cart. which i have to built on Java. which Session maintenance technology is best (hidden file, cookies, URL rewriting or other) for session maintenance when connection lost is highly concern due to power lose in some contries (disconnect) while shopping

Comment: I would think: If you want the cart on the user's machine, cookies. If you want it on your server, a db. And it really has little to do with "session maintenance" per se. You should never put the whole session just in a cookie or any other type of client-side concept...but the cart, that's probably fine.

Comment: If you have an account and have ever bought anything from amazon, you'll see they do it both ways. If you just put stuff in your cart, or are not yet logged in, its in a cookie I think. But if you login then click "save for later" on an item, it goes in their db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can give redis a shot.
http://redis.io/

Redis is an open source, BSD licensed, advanced key-value cache and store. It is often referred to as a data structure server since keys can contain strings, hashes, lists, sets, sorted sets, bitmaps and hyperloglogs.

One way to save cart session is to create a random cart id then put it on browser cookie then save the random cart id into redis server so every time a user will add an item on your cart update the redis server using the cart id as key then update the value of that key with the data that you need. BTW redis can handle objects in value.

Even if there will be a power failure the data is stored on the server and using the stored cart id in the browser cookie you can retrieve the data.

I have a project that is already using redis especially on cart.
Check http://www.metrosix.com/